# generating UUID in Ubuntu OS

Tags: ubuntu, uuid

How to generate uuid in ubuntu, I am using Anjuta IDE.

Regards,
iSight

Comment: The same way that you would normally. (Which I leave up to you to figure out - or to make the question meaningful.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need a new guid, there are a ton of places online to make one for you e.g. http://www.newguid.net/Guid_Generator.aspx

If you need a C guid library, there is libuuid which is available in your ubuntu repository.